# UICollectionViewCell not updating image if visible

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a CollectionView which shows thumbnails after loading. At the beginning, the pictures are not stored on the device so they get fetched from the server. In a callback method after fetching these images from the server they cells don't get updated, i need to scroll them out of the screen, then they get updated. I had a similar mechanism in another app, there everything worked fine and I can't find the difference. Below are some parts of the code for better understanding what I do.

This is the code where i set the image after checking if the thumbnail is already fetched from the server. If so, set it directly, if not, retrieve the picture using Alamofire and update it after finish loading.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PictureCollectionViewCell

    /* Set thumbnail to the cell */
    if let thumbnail = pictures[indexPath.row].thumbnail {
        cell.imageView.image = thumbnail
    } else {
        pictures[indexPath.row].retrievePicture(thumbnail: true, completion: { picture in
            cell.imageView.image = picture
        })
    }

    return cell
}
```

As said before, it's not updating until I scroll the cell out of the visible screen area. cell or collectionView reloads didn't fix the problem. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the closure `retrievePicture()` called? What the code from that?

Comment: By the time your image downloads, cell display is completed. You need to call `reloadData()` on the collection view to refresh the UI.

Comment: What thread is the completion of the download run on?

Comment: `retrievePicture()` is just an Alamofire web request loading the image and passing it into the callback method

Comment: Some other components on the screen outside the collectionView get updated by a callback method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, it was the dumbest error you can imagine. Updating the UI from an asynchronous callback method just works fine. I just forgot to call the callback method from the async task. Problem solved, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

because the block execute in background thread. you have to update UI in main thread.  use this code below

```
pictures[indexPath.row].retrievePicture(thumbnail: true, completion: { picture in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   cell.imageView.image = picture
                }
        })
```

Comment: It doesn't changed the behaviour

Answer (score 2):

You might find it better to simply reload the items at the indexPath instead of reloading the entire table using:

```
collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(yourIndexPath)
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetching is probably happening in the background thread so your callback function is called from it too. UI cannot be updated from the  the background thread. 
So in your fetching callback try to use something like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Or

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   collectionView.reloadItems(indexPaths)
}
```

Comment: Same behaviour as before, didn't changed anything